# Memory Leak (Google Chrome) handling images using Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I am new here and I have got a problem with memory leak.
I use a jquery framework called Leanorama to create a virtual tour.

My problem is that when go through the tour and visit different enviroments the amount of memory consumed by my application is increased in 200MB. So visiting only five different places it will get at least 1GB. Google Chrome never releases that memory and the page crashes   because that (the memory is released only if I reload the page, but I go to the beginning of the tour again).

Probably some of you have found the same problem as me.

This is my main js file
/* Variable which contains all the attributes require to initialize the virtual tour */

```
var tour = {
        entrance: entrance,
        museumCenter: museumCenter,
        expo1: expo1,
        expo2: expo2,
        expo3: expo3,
        expo4: expo4,
        expo5: expo5,
        expo6: expo6,
        expo7: expo7,
        expo8: expo8,
        expo9: expo9,
        expo10: expo10,
        expo11: expo11,
        expo12: expo12,
        expo13: expo13,
        expo14: expo14,
        downCorner01: downCorner01,
        middleEntranceCorridor: middleEntranceCorridor,
        downCorner02: downCorner02,
        middleSkeletonCorridor: middleSkeletonCorridor,
        downCorner03: downCorner03,
        middlePosteriorCorridor: middlePosteriorCorridor,
        downCorner04: downCorner04,
        middleSideCorridor: middleSideCorridor,
        dino: dino,
        gallery01: gallery01,
        gallery02: gallery02,
        gallery03: gallery03,
        gallery04: gallery04,
        gallery05: gallery05,
        gallery06: gallery06,
        gallery07: gallery07,
        gallery08: gallery08
    };

/* Initializing the function tour and attributing at the #pano html id */

$('#pano').leanorama(tour.entrance).on('leanoramaHotspotClick', function(e, hotspot) {
    if (hotspot.type == 'nav') $(this).trigger('leanoramaRefresh', tour[hotspot.value]);
});

/* Click event of the map */

$('.map').click(function (){
    $('#pano').leanorama(tour[$(this).attr('value')]).on('leanoramaHotspotClick', 
        function(e, hotspot) {
            if (hotspot.type == 'nav') $(this).trigger('leanoramaRefresh', tour[hotspot.value]);
        }); 
});

/* event to hide/show the map */
$('#pano').dblclick(function (){
    if ($("img").is(":hidden")){
        $("img").show();
    }
    else
        $("img").hide();
});
```

Do you know how I could solve it? A way to force Chrome to release the memory of previous environment and just keep in memory the current environment?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Do you have any idea how could I solve it?

Comment: No, that would be impossible as you haven't provided the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Clive, this is the framework I am using.
https://github.com/leandigo/leanorama

They have a sample code there. I think it is easier to understand if I just post the link.

Thanks

Comment: It isn't - if you want help with code you've written, you need to include a sample that can be used to reproduce the problem. That information needs to be in your question, not elsewhere. These are the site rules, you can read them for yourself in the [help]

Comment: Thanks for telling me that Clive. I just edited my question.